# Using Four Conditions in a Case When Statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there's a way to use at least four conditionals in a case when statement in MYSQL.

```
CASE 
   WHEN 
       rank = 0 AND 
       visibility != 'visibile' AND 
       rank = 1 AND 
       visibility = 'visibile' 
   THEN 'Yes'
   WHEN 
       rank = 1 AND 
       visibility != 'visibile' AND 
       rank = 2 AND 
       visibility = 'visibile' 
   THEN 'Yes' 
   WHEN 
       rank = 2 AND 
       visibility != 'visibile' AND 
       rank = 3 AND 
       visibility = 'visibile' 
   THEN 'Yes' 
   ELSE null 
END 'Missing in Sequence'
```

When ever I use more than 2 conditionals I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify, what you mean by "I cant seem to get it to work"?

Comment: Meaning it doesn't work as intended. When I run this I don't get "Yes" when rank 0 is not in field and rank 1 is in field.

Comment: @Juergen I know, for instance, that in this table I'm looking at rank 0 is not visible, but rank 1 is, so why when I run this query are both coming back as null? rank 0 should come back as a Yes.

Comment: I have no experience with CASE WHEN Statements, but I would guess, that  the statement of Rigel is true: Your statements are contradicting. You say, that it is for two different ranks, but how should the db know that? When you say rank == 1 and rank == 2 it is just a contradiction, because the database is applying it to the *same* row. I guess, you want to apply it to two different rows. I guess, that is one of the cases, where a join must be made -- and you have to qualify your field names, so that different fields (for example p.rank and q.rank) can be distinguished. Post table scheme.

Comment: @Juergen, shouldn't it know because i said "(rank = 0 and visibility != 'visible') and (rank = 1 and visibility = 'visible')"?

Comment: @Juergen, all the ranks are from the same table

Comment: How should it know? Databases are very bad in AI.

Comment: @Juergen I just joined the same table under a different name and I still get the same results, so it can't be because it thinks both visibilities are the same

Comment: Show the table scheme and your Join, this would be a basis for further discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will never work logically. Because, `visibility = 'visibile'` and `visibility != 'visibile'` are contradicting each other in every case. So, I tried to correct your `CASE` statement by creating a nested `CASE` statement.Try it:

```
CASE WHEN 
     ((SELECT visibility  FROM table WHERE rank=0)!='visibile' AND 
     (SELECT visibility  FROM table WHERE rank=1)='visibile')
 THEN 'Yes'
 WHEN
 ((SELECT visibility  FROM table WHERE rank=1)!='visibile' AND 
     (SELECT visibility  FROM table WHERE rank=2)='visibile') 
 THEN 'Yes' 
 WHEN
     ((SELECT visibility  FROM table WHERE rank=2)!='visibile' AND 
     (SELECT visibility  FROM table WHERE rank=3)='visibile')  
 THEN 'Yes' 
ELSE 'Missing in Sequence' END
```

Comment: Hi Rigel, I don't think OR will work in this case because I'm trying to find missing instances in a sequence, so I need it to say AND. Also, the visibility =/!= 'visible' thing should be logical because it is for two separate ranks, not for the same rank. I want to say that IF rank 0 is not visible, but rank one is, then it's missing in sequence, etc.

Comment: So, for example, rank 0 is not visible, but rank 1 is. When I use your suggestion I get a "Yes", but that's only because with your  code I will always get a Yes if one condition is met. However, I want a "Yes" because rank 0 is not visible AND because rank 1 is.

Comment: Thanks, but adding parentheses did not help. I do not return a Yes when I should. I keep getting a null when I should be getting a Yes.